# java map values from an object

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I am new to collections and looking for help.  I am trying to search a map using a key, and return the values of the key which is from another object.  This is my code so far.

```
public class Employer {
    Map<String, NewHire> employee = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addEmployee(String fullName, String age, String location, String JobTitle) {
    NewHire newEmployee = new NewHire(age, location, JobTitle);
    this.employee.put(fullName, newEmployee);
}
```

The code for the other object is -

```
public class NewHire {
    private String age;
    private String location;
    private String jobTitle;
}

public NewHire(String aAge, String aLocation, String aJobTitle) {
    this.age = aAge;
     this.location = aLocation;
     this.jobTitle = aJobTitle;
}
```

I then create like so -

```
Employer CompanyA = new Employer();

CompanyA.addEmployee("JohnSmith", "23", "London", "Service Desk");
```

I wanted to create a method that can search the map for a key specified by the user, in this case "JohnSmith", and if found, it then shows me the age, location and jobTitle of that person but I really am not sure how I would go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about it in my opinion is the way **Titulum** said, using Optional. 
I would just leave another way, a bit not so nice, but you may understand it better.

You can **Override** the `toString()` method in the `NewHire` class and use it, or create getters for the properties:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return String.format("Age: %s\nLocation: %s\nJobTitle: %s", age, location, jobTitle);
}

// getters
public String getJobTitle() {
    return jobTitle;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

On your `Employer` class, if you want to use the not so much nicer way of doing it (although i recommend using Optional):

```
public NewHire getEmployeeByName(String fullName){
    return employee.get(fullName);
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Employer employer = new Employer();
employer.addEmployee("JohnSmith", "23", "London", "Service Desk");

NewHire newHire = employer.getEmployeeByName("sJohnSmith");

if(newHire != null) {
    System.out.println(newHire.toString());

    // using getters
    System.out.println(newHire.getAge());
    System.out.println(newHire.getJobTitle());
    System.out.println(newHire.getLocation());
}
```

Comment: No need to explicitly call `toString()` for `System.out.println()` as one of the overloaded methods of `println()` takes `Object` as parameter and internally, that will call `toString()` if the object passed is not null, else just "null". So, if the purpose is just to print, no need of explicit null check also

Comment: We have not been taught Optional as of yet (that comes later), so I wouldn't be able to use it for now :(

Comment: @NewtoJavaHelp Then you can use it like that, if you don't want to use the toString() method, you can create getters for all the properties and use them instead.

Comment: @NewtoJavaHelp If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write the method as follows:

```java
public Optional<NewHire> findByFullName(String fullName) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(employee.get(fullName));
}
```

This will return you an `Optional`, which is an Object in Java that contains either something or nothing. To see if the `Optional` contains anything you can do:

```java
Optional<NewHire> possiblyFoundNewHire = findByFullName("SomeName");
possibleFoundNewHire.ifPresent(newHire -> {
  System.out.println(newHire); // Or formatted as you would like.
});
```

Comment: We have not been taught Optional as of yet (that comes later), so I wouldn't be able to use it for now :(